# How to create this layout in Android code?

Tags: android

UPDATE: problem solved. There is a litle bug in my real code. The below code work fine. Thanks all so so much for the supports!

==================================================================================
I have a linear layout and some text view like below. The Linear layout is in horizontall orientation. The below layout works as I want, but I want to add TextView to it dynamically, so I want to initialize it in code instead of xml. But when I do it in code, the text view appear on top of linear layout instead of bottom like I want. The xml layout file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:baselineAligned="false">
      <TextView 
           android:text="dfg dfg dfg dfg dfg dfg dfg dfg dfg dfg dfg dfg dfg dfg dfg dfg dfg dfg dfg dfg"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:background="#eeffee"
           android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

      <TextView 
           android:text="asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:background="#eeeeff"
           android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>


      <TextView 
           android:text="qweoiu qweoiuqwe oiqwe qwoeiu qweoiu qweoiuq weoiuqw eoiquw eoiqwue oqiweu qowieu qowieu qoiweu qowieu qowieu qowieu qowieu qoiweu qowieu qoiwue "
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:background="#ffeeee"
           android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

My code is:

```
    LinearLayout container = new LinearLayout(getContext());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    container.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    container.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    container.setBaselineAligned(false);

    TextView textView = new TextView(getContext());
    textView.setText("asgfg fgf");
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
    layoutParams1.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
    textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1);
    container.addView(textView);

    TextView textView2 = new TextView(getContext());
    textView2.setText("asgfg fgf");
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
    layoutParams2.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
    textView2.setLayoutParams(layoutParams2);
    container.addView(textView2);

    TextView textView3 = new TextView(getContext());
    textView3.setText("asgfg fgf");
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams3 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
    layoutParams3.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
    textView3.setLayoutParams(layoutParams3);
    container.addView(textView3);
```

My code does not work, the Text View appear on top instead of bottom. Please help me take a look to see what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: android:gravity="bottom" in your Linearlayout

Comment: That xml layout file works fine and all text view appear on bottom as I want. My problem is that I want to convert that xml layout to code, it means initialize them in code, not in xml file. The code is above, but that code does not works.

Comment: layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;

Comment: for this you have to provide id to all the views in your xml file and then get those views in your .java file from xml using those ids

Comment: tried, but not work too

Comment: Why create a layout in code instead of in an XML layout file? All you have to do is add the `TextView` to your XML layout file and set its visibility (in code) to GONE if you don't need it or VISIBLE if you do.

Comment: In my real situation, the number of text view depends on number of data item.

Answer (score 0):

Setting gravity for TextView just says where its text should be placed - not the view. You must use layout_gravity or gravity param of layout (parent's gravity or gravity param of LayoutParams) but not TextView's gravity.

**EDITED**

```
((LinearLayout.LayoutParams)myTextView.getLayoutParams()).gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
```

**EDITED AGAIN**

```
LinearLayout container = new LinearLayout(getContext());
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
container.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: I also tried set the LayoutParams's gravity property of linear layout but it does not works too.

Comment: again, the layout above works fine. You can paste it to your IDE to see how it works. I'm just trying to convert that layout to code.

Comment: You should set layout gravity property of TextView or gravity of parent's layout not layout property of parent's layout!

Comment: I just found gravity property in LayoutPrams class, not layoutGravity peropery or any other similar method to set layout gravity. I also cannot find how to set layout gravity property of Textview.

Comment: See edited answer, if you use LinearLayout you should cast LayoutParams to LinearLayout.LayoutParams to get LinearLayout's params

Comment: yes, I also do this, pls read my code again. You can see the line:

 layoutParams2.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
    textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams2);

Comment: And I see that u used textView not textView2 to set layoutParams2 on it ;)

Comment: Good find. But I have tried but it does not works too.

Comment: Try to add layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM; as in code in my again edited answer

Answer (score 0):

If in your onCreate you are using

```
setContentView(R.layout.your_xml);
```

than you have to go with Deepzz answer.
or you can use

```
setContentView(container);
```